# how to filter events with the eventbrite wordpress api

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating an event page on wordpress that pulls the eventbrite events data including thumbnails, title, descriptions, cities, etc and since, there are so many events, I would like to add a way to filter the events by which city or which organizer it is from eventbrite with a drop down. I am using https://github.com/Automattic/eventbrite-api for our wordpress site.

This is the work I have done so far and I am stuck.

Also, I am very new to wordpress and php. So everything I have done so far, I am amazed at myself on how I figured it out. I have one more part and I need support.

I figured out that to get organizer, it is `get_the_author_meta('ID'))` and to get the city is `eventbrite_event_venue()->address->city`

So what I need support in figuring out is how to get all the cities in a dropdown so when the user selects it. it will be organized by that city. and another drop down when the user select the author, the events only show by that author.

So inside page-events.php

```
    <?php
    // Set up and call our Eventbrite query.
    $events = new Eventbrite_Query( apply_filters( 
       'eventbrite_query_args', array(
        'display_private' => true, // boolean
        'status' => 'live',         // string (only available for 
         display_private true)
        'nopaging' => true,        // boolean
        // 'limit' => 5,            // integer
        // 'organizer_id' => null,     // integer
        // 'p' => null,                // integer
        // 'post__not_in' => null,     // array of integers
        // 'venue_id' => null,         // integer
        // 'category_id' => null,      // integer
        // 'subcategory_id' => null,   // integer
        // 'format_id' => null,        // integer
    ) ) );
    if ( $events->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $events->have_posts() ) : $events->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'events' ); 
?>

        <?php endwhile;
        // Previous/next post navigation.
        eventbrite_paging_nav();
    else :
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
    endif;
    // Return $post to its rightful owner.
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

and inside content-events.php, I have

```
     <article id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
          <div class="border bg-white clear container box-shadow events-container 
       mb-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 p-0 events-image-container">
                <img src="<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id(); ?>" 
             alt="">
            </div>



            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 px-4 mt-3">
                    <p class="m-1 font-weight-bold">


                        <?php eventbrite_event_organizer(); ?>
                        <?php
                                // everything available
                                foreach((get_the_category()) as 
                                 $category) {
                                    echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
                                }
                                ?>
                    </p>

                    <?php eventbrite_event_meta() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

for the function eventbrite_event_meta(), I have created

```
  if (!function_exists('eventbrite_event_meta')) {
  /**
   * Output event information such as date, time, venue, and organizer
   */
  function eventbrite_event_meta()
  {

    // Add a contextual link to event details.
    if (eventbrite_is_single()) {
            // Link to event info on eventbrite.com.
            $url = add_query_arg(array('ref' => 'wporglink'), 
            eventbrite_event_eb_url());
    } else {
            // Link to the event single view.
            $url = eventbrite_event_eb_url();
    }

    if (!function_exists('eventbrite_event_time')) {
        /**
         * Return an event's time.
         *
         * @return string Event time.
         */
        function eventbrite_event_time()
        {
        // Determine if the end time needs the date included (in the case of multi-day events).
        $end_time = eventbrite_is_multiday_event() ? mysql2date('F j Y, g:i A', eventbrite_event_end()->local) : mysql2date('g:i A', eventbrite_event_end()->local);
        // Assemble the full event time string.
        $event_time = sprintf(_x('%1$s - %2$s', 'Event date and time. %1$s = start time, %2$s = end time', 'eventbrite_api'), esc_html(mysql2date('F j Y, g:i A', eventbrite_event_start()->local)), esc_html($end_time));
            return $event_time;
        }
    }
    if (!function_exists('eventbrite_is_multiday_event')) {
        /**
         * Determine if an event spans multiple calendar days.
         *
         * @return bool True if start and end date are the same, false otherwise.
         */
        function eventbrite_is_multiday_event()
        {
            // Set date variables for comparison.
            $start_date = mysql2date('Ymd', eventbrite_event_start()->utc);
            $end_date = mysql2date('Ymd', eventbrite_event_end()->utc);
            // Return true if they're different, false otherwise.
            return $start_date !== $end_date;
        }
        }

    // Add the organizer's name if available. Author-related functions are filtered to use the event's organizer.
    $organizer = '';
    if (!empty(eventbrite_event_organizer()->name)) {
            $organizer = sprintf('<li class="event-organizer"><span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span><a class="event-organizer-link url fn n" href="%s">%s</a></li>', esc_html__('Organizer', 'writr'), esc_url(eventbrite_event_eb_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))), esc_html(get_the_author()));
    }
    // Add a venue name if available.
 $venue = '';
 if (!empty(eventbrite_event_venue()->address->city)) {
         $venue = sprintf('<li class="event-venue"><span class="screen- 
 reader-text">%s</span><a class="event-venue-link url fn n" href="%s">%s</a> .     </li>', esc_html__('Venue', 'writr'), esc_url($url), 
 esc_html(eventbrite_event_venue()->address->city));
 }

 apply_filters('eventbrite_event_start', get_post()->start);



    // Start with the event time.
 $time = sprintf('<li class="event-time"><span class="screen-reader- 
 text">%s</span><p class="m-0">%s</p></li>', esc_html__('Event date and 
 time', 'writr'), eventbrite_event_time());

    // title of Event
 $title_meta = get_the_title();
 $title = sprintf( '<li class="entry-title h2 m-0 mb-4 font-weight- 
 bold"><a href="%s" target="_blank" rel="bookmark">%s</a></li>', 
 esc_url($url), esc_html__($title_meta, 'writr'));

 // Determine if the end time needs the date included (in the case of 
multi-day events).
$event_date_start = eventbrite_is_multiday_event() ? mysql2date('l, F 
j', eventbrite_event_start()->local) : mysql2date('l, F j', 
eventbrite_event_start()->local);
$event_date = sprintf(_x('<li class="event-time">%1$s</li>', 'Event 
date and time. %1$s = start time', 'eventbrite_api'), 
esc_html($event_date_start));


 // Determine if the end time needs the date included (in the case of 
multi-day events).
$event_time_start = eventbrite_is_multiday_event() ? mysql2date('g:iA', 
eventbrite_event_start()->local) : mysql2date('g:iA', 
eventbrite_event_start()->local);
$event_time_end = eventbrite_is_multiday_event() ? mysql2date('g:iA', 
eventbrite_event_end()->local) : mysql2date('g:iA', 
eventbrite_event_end()->local);

 // Add a venue name if available.
$room = '';
if (!empty(eventbrite_event_venue()->address->address_2)) {
    $room = sprintf('<li class="event-venue"><span class="screen- 
    reader-text">%1$s - %2$s @ %3$s</span><a class="event-venue-link url fn n" 
    href="%4$s">%1$s - %2$s @ %3$s</a></li>', esc_html($event_time_start), 
    esc_html($event_time_end), esc_html(eventbrite_event_venue()->address- 
   >address_2), esc_url($url));
} else {
                // Assemble the full event time string.
        $room = sprintf(_x('<li class="event-venue">%1$s - %2$s</li>', 
  'Event date and time. %1$s = start time, %2$s = end time', 
  'eventbrite_api'), esc_html($event_time_start), 
  esc_html($event_time_end));
} ;

$details = sprintf('<li class="event-details mt-2"><a class="event- 
details-link btn btn-outline-dark font-weight-bold m-0" role="button" 
target="_blank" href="%s">%s</a></li>', esc_url($url), 
esc_html__('RSVP', 'writr'));
// Add an event Edit link.
$edit = '';
if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
     $url = add_query_arg(array('eid' => get_the_ID(), 'ref' => 
'wporgedit'), '<a class="vglnk" href="https://eventbrite.com/edit" 
 rel="nofollow"><span>https</span><span>://</span><span>eventbrite</span> . 
 <span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>edit</span></a>');
     $edit = sprintf('<li class="event-edit"><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', 
 esc_url($url), esc_html__('Edit', 'writr'));
}
// Assemble our HTML. Yugly.
$html = sprintf('<ul class="clear events-container"><div class="row 
header mb-4 text-uppercase"><div class="col-sm-6 p-3 mb-2">%1$s</div> 
<div 
class="col-sm-6 bg-dark text-white text-center p-3 mb-2">%2$s</div> . 
</div>%3$s%4$s%5$s%6$s</ul>', $organizer, $venue, $event_date, $title, 
$room, $details);
echo apply_filters('eventbrite_event_meta', $html, $organizer, $venue, 
$event_date, $title, $room, $details);
  }
 }
```

Comment: You could try something like this: loop through `$events` and fill an array with the event cities using `eventbrite_event_venue()->address->city`. Then remove duplicate cities using `array_unique`. Use this array to build a simple HTML `<select>` dropdown. The form of this dropdown will submit using `method="get"`, so the city name will be appended to the page url, like `mysite.org?city=amsterdam`. In your event loop in `page-events.php` you could then simply check whether the current event city equals the one from your GET parameter. A better way would be to use the API  for filtering.

Comment: @Michael I understand all of this. So when i get the data from the api. It is giving me seperate arrays for each city. how do i merge all the arrays. the arrays are all the same name.

Comment: follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392648/figure-out-how-to-merge-array-for-filter-loop